# pdbstr does not work from outside of the installation folder

Tags: pdb-files, source-server

I try to setup source server without SVC- I want to use a simple UNC path as a source storage.

I made small console project with a single file and try to make it source indexed.

I have following stream file:

```
SRCSRV: ini ------------------------------------------------
VERSION=1
INDEXVERSION=2
VERCTRL=Test
DATETIME=Mon, 04 October 2010
SRCSRV: variables ------------------------------------------
SRCSRVTRG=
SRCSRVCMD=cmd /c "copy" %var2 %targ%
SRCSRV: source files ---------------------------------------
C:\Users\mb\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\TestSymbolServer\Program.cs*\\mbvirt-pc\symserver\source\Program.cs
SRCSRV: end ------------------------------------------------
```

When I try to write to my pdb with use of pdbstr like this:

```
pdbstr -w -p:"C:\Users\mb\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\TestSymbolServer\bin\Release\TestSymbolServer.pdb" -i:srcsrv -s:"C:\Users\mb\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\TestSymbolServer\bin\Release\symbols.txt"
```

I getting only this response:

```
C:\Users\mb\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\TestSymbolServer\bin\Release>p
dbstr -w -p:"C:\Users\mb\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\TestSymbolServer\
bin\Release\TestSymbolServer.pdb" -i:srcsrv -s:"C:\Users\mb\Documents\Visual Stu
dio 2010\Projects\TestSymbolServer\bin\Release\symbols.txt"
pdbstr -r/w -p:PdbFileName -i:StreamFileName -s:StreamName
```

When I check pdb with srctool I can see that nothing was written. And moreover- I'm getting the same response when I try to read stream from the pdb like this

```
"C:\Program Files\Debugging Tools for Windows (x64)\srcsrv\pdbstr" -r -p:"C:\Users\mb\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\TestSymbolServer\bin\Release\TestSymbolServer.pdb" -i:srcsrv
```

Could this be an issue with pdbstr or in my environment? Can I somehow get logs from pdbstr?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My laziness is appeared to be the root of all evil.

I have added "C:\Program Files\Debugging Tools for Windows (x64)\srcsrv" to system path variables and run pdbstr from folder were my local project resides. Looks like pdbstr has some dependencies in install folder.

So it should be called from the original location.

Short path long problems list :-(